# Database error occurred (SQL error 18054) when mapping local directory in TFS

Tags: sql-server, tfs, error-handling

I'm using VS2010 as a client for a TFS instance.  I created a workspace, and need to map a TFS directory to a local directory - let's call the local directory "**D:\aaa\bbb\ccc\ddd**".  When I navigate to "Manage Workspaces"  and click "edit" to change the local directory to this path, I am presented with the following error: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YV5K.png)

This error occurs when I try to map:  "**D:\aaa**", "**D:\aaa\bbb**", "**D:\aaa\bbb\ccc**".

Now, if I create a folder called:  "**D:\aaa\bbb\ccc1\ddd**", the mapping works, and I do not receive this error.

Can anyone help?  I've been pulling my hair out for about a day over this.

Thank you.

[EDIT01:  I tried mapping all other folders under the D:\ drive, and only one other folder fails the mapping.  I receive the same error as with "**D:\aaa\bbb\ccc\ddd**" ]

Comment: (For search indexing)The error message says: A database error occurred (SQL error 18054) ---> Error 500053, severity 16, state 1 was raised, but no message with that error number was Found in sys.messages. 
If error is larger than 50000, make sure the user-defined message is added using sp_addmessage.

Error 500016, severity 16, state 1 was raised, but no message with that error number was found in sys.messages. If error is larger than 50000, make sure the user-defined message is added using sp_addmessage

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**SQL Errors**

First of all, you should not be receiving SQL Error 18054 (or any SQL errors) from TFS.

You should have your TFS administrator connect to the SQL server that hosts the `master` DB for your TFS server and run the following query:

```
select * from master.dbo.sysmessages where error > 50000
```

If this is a TFS2010 server, your TFS administrator may be able to use [TFSConfig PrepSql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee349267.aspx) to re-install the error messages.

If this is a TFS2008 server, your TFS administrator will need to open Add/Remove programs and run a **repair** on TFS.

**Your actual problem**

> This sounds obvious at first, two
>   local paths cannot point to the same
>   place in the repository for the same
>   workspace. However, the one that
>   catches a lot of folks un-aware is
>   that you cannot have two repository
>   paths mapped to one local path on the
>   same computer.

In TFS, you cannot have two folders with overlapping mappings. Since `D:\aaa\bbb\ccc\ddd` is a sub-folder of  `D:\aaa`, then you cannot add it.

One thing you can do though, is **cloak** folders so that they aren't part of the workspace mappings. In your case, you might want to map `D:\aaa` and add a cloak for all the other subfolders in that directory, except for `D:\aaa\bbb`.

Comment: thanks for the answer.  the problem turned out to be that, somehow, multiple workspaces were pointing to the same directory.  i mapped to a different directory on the local drive, and everything is working.

Comment: this question is closed so I can only add a comment - but you can also get this if you've done something unsupported like take a hard drive out containing a workspace and loaded it on a different workstation (that has created its own workspace) and then try to check it in (or do anything source related with it). the source control information will be pointing to the wrong place and it will get all confused. you just need to 'change source control' and rebind it - and probably run a diff to make sure nothing is missed

Comment: and if that doesn't work and you still get errors then use TFS Workspace Sidekick - http://www.attrice.info/cm/tfs/ - and delete workspace from any defunct computers (I just deleted the workspace from my tempoary workstation via the sidekick on my normal workstation and all these errors went away). MAKE BACKUP FIRST OF LOCAL FILES just to be sure before messing with things like this. (my primary workstation had to go in for repair which is why i was doing this)

Comment: note: if after you've changed source control you get certain files with no lock or checkmark next to them it means you have a conflict that needs resolving. you need to do a get latest (which you can do recursively or on a single file) and resolve the conflict. if all else fails and you still get this error when trying to 'go online' you can try deselecting the files in the 'go online' list