# files not check in , In TFS

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

Team foundation server working fine every day, but today it give errors.

> Problem:

Files are not check In.

> Detail:

I complete my code and when press check in button in visual studio it gives me error:

> TF246021: An error occurred while processing your request. Technical
>   information (for administrator): SQL Server Error: 18054

This problem also face on other team member systems.

> solution so far apply but not able to resolve:

1. Delete work space and create new one.
2. Restart my server.

Using visual studio 2013, local team foundation server.

[Another question but have different sql-server error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14746267/how-to-solve-tfs-error-tf246021-and-sql-server-error-500200-while-checking-in)

Comment: Seem like a SQL server problem. Check SQL server storage and logfiles. If possible try to restart your SQL server

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/14746267/736079

Comment: @jessehouwing it is not duplicate question other question have different sql-server error. and also have no answer. so i think so you marked duplicate mistakenly.

Comment: The steps to figure out what's wrong are the same, dig into the eventlog of the Application  tier to find the underlying cause and resolve that. We can't answer your question without it and the error is very likely caused by the workspace mappings and an old version of TFS.

Comment: Plus, it was closed against: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5356242/database-error-occurred-sql-error-18054-when-mapping-local-directory-in-tfs

Comment: @jessehouwing we are working on this TFS for years and have same workspace mapping. but this problem comes today.

Comment: can you help me out, how dig into the eventlog of the application tier.

Comment: Open Eventviewer on the server running your TFS server and look for errors in the application log related to SQL.

Comment: @jessehouwing 
Error 480000, severity 16, state 1 was raised, but no message with that error number was found in sys.messages.
Error 500200, severity 16, state 1 was raised, but no message with that error number was found in sys.messages. If error is larger than 50000, make sure the user-defined message is added using sp_addmessage.

Comment: your TFS administrator may be able to use `TFSConfig PrepSql` to re-install the error messages.

Comment: I suspect there is another workspace mapping on your system that maps the same folder(s). Try deleting all workspaces from the server for your computer. this could also happen when someone else is using the same computer name (using a VM for example).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193780/discussion-between-jessehouwing-and-ali-imran).

Comment: according to this old connect item, this is a bug in TFS 2010 and is resolved in TFS 2012 or later. What TFS version are you using?

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20130313194224/http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/693450/tfs-2010-violation-of-primary-key-constraint-pk-tbl-pendingdelta